# Selenium Webdriver code in Java to search hidden Objects in Web Browser

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java

I am trying to create a Selenium Web driver java code where I can find all the hidden objects on the webpage and can be accessed. I want the count of all those hidden objects. Which property I can use in the code which can identify hidden objects because when I thought of using get Element by property so that i can search for objects with hidden property, it was not there. Is there anything i am missing here. Is it really possible ? Or do we need to know the id of the element to be found ? Any Inputs will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What kind of hidden objects are you looking for? If it's any HTML tags with the attribute `display: none;` try using

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[display=none]"));
int count = elements.size();
```

This uses CSS matching to find all HTML elements with the display attribute equal to none. Then get the size of the returned list with the `size()` method.

Comment: Thanks for that and my aim here is to find all the objects that are in the web page but are hidden, could be Html elements or not. Is it feasible ?

Comment: From my experience hidden webpage elements would have either display:none or visibility:hidden.

Comment: Or they could be simply hidden behind an overlay, or with ajax it is sometimes common to actually remove unused elements from the dom and re-add them when needed.  As Francis noted - looking for the styles display=none and visibility:hidden will find you all of the elements that are hidden via CSS and styling.

Comment: Hey Francis. I tried running the code you suggested both ways but i am still getting the count as 0. is there anything which needs to be rectified. I tried testing it on multiple websites but its not getting me any output. Please help.

Comment: Try replacing display=none with visibility=hidden. If the count is still 0 then the elements aren't hidden by CSS but might be either under an overlay or removed from the DOM as Sam noted.

Comment: Yes Tried with both. Any way to get the elements under an overlay ? They must be hidden with some property which we can take advantage of

Comment: If it's removed from the DOM it's going to be trickier. You'll need knowledge of what JavaScript is run on page load and then you can assert if the element isn't found. If it's hidden by an overlay you can assert if the overlay is visible instead of the element being hidden. Both ways if it's not hidden with CSS I believe you'll need knowledge of the JavaScript and any Ajax calls.

Comment: Fine. Thanks a lot Francis. I'll work on that.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the long option which uses selenium's element displayed functionality.

[W3C specifications for element displayed](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-element-displayed)

Python example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

b = webdriver.Chome()
b.get('https://google.com')
els = b.find_elements_by_css_selector('*')
hidden_els = [el for el in els if not el.is_displayed()]
print(hidden_els)
b.quit()
```